# How can I pass query string from one jsp page to another jsp page without showing the name-value pair at address bar?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, query-string

I want to send a query string from one jsp page to jsp page but I want to hide the name-value pairs(attributes) at address bar when I send the query string.

**First.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>First Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="Second.jsp?username=aditya123&password=abc12345">Click Here</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Second.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Second Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
        %>
        Username : <%=username %><br/>
        Password : <%=password %><br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here, I pass a query string **`"Second.jsp?username=aditya123&password=abc12345"`** from `First.jsp` page to `Second.jsp` page but I want to send this without showing **username** and **password** attribute and their value at address bar.How can it possible?

Comment: you can try form with hidden fields

Comment: Yes,I know it is possible with form tag and hidden attributes but I need to send it with query string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<form action="some.jsp" method="post">
<input type="text" name="uid" >
<input type="password" name="pass">
<input type="submit" name="login" >
</form>
```

Adding method ="post" hides the query stringThat is ,if i remove ' method="post"  ' the processed url on pressing submit button would be having
Following as query string

> uid="whatever i wrote in text field"&pass=""&login="Submit"

But after writing ' method="post" ' the new url will be free of query string...!

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible with link.
alternate solution of not showing attribute is encode that name value pair and send it with url and decode at another page.

use either  url encoder  given by java or make use of your own encrypt-decrypt method.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is   `<form action="some.jsp" method="post">`

Do this formatting in the html code.
And contents of url will be hidden...

Comment: You should show the full code example and explain, so the person asking the question knows exactly what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the objects/information you want to pass to the second jsp file by storing the objects in the 'session' implicit object using session.setAttribute() method. In the second page you can retrieve those objects from the 'session' object using session.getAttribute(). My assumption here is that both the jsp pages are being executed in the same HttpSession, hence the same 'session' object will be available to both the jsp pages.